# That is hurting!

Tags: present-continuous

1. If you hit your leg just a second ago, and still feel the pain, you say:

either  "Ouch! That **hurt**!", Or  "Ouch! That **hurts**!"

Do we say: "Ouch! That **is hurting**!"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Some verbs (hurt, live) are used in the simple present to describe current state.

> I live in New York.  My leg hurts.

With these verbs you can use continuous if you want to particularly emphasise that a state is *temporary*.  It started recently and is expected to end soon.

> I'm living in New York until I earn enough to move to the suburbs. My leg is hurting after falling over [but it will get better]

We could use "That is hurting me" to say that something is currently causing pain, but if you remove it the pain will stop. But it is rather unusual. The normal expression to describe a state of pain is "that hurts!"

Comment: But traditional grammar uses the **simple present** form for **stative verbs** to refer to both permanent and temporary states, right?

Answer (score 2):

I would use "That hurt/hurts!" [ since it sounds very common to my ear ] with very little difference in meaning, at least tense-wise.

But using "hurt" in present continuous would imply either *"cause pain to"* or *"feel down/distress"*:

e.g. Ouch! That's hurting me! ( this use of the present continuous seems to put special/additional emphasis on a *continuous / extended / temporary* process of *causing/feeling* pain. );

Note that I added an object to the verb in my first example, and when talking about the meaning I mentioned previously, a person who is down, I would say: "He was hurting badly. [Intransitive]"

Your present continuous example doesn't sound convincingly idiomatic.